# Proxy settings in C#, web service

Tags: c#, credentials

I wanted to set the credentials (username, password) for connecting to a web service from the internet and  i put them in a proxy which looks like this:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(); 
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
serv.Proxy = proxy;
```

WebProxy also takes as params an address and a port. What would that mean in my  case (localhost and a port whatever) or shall i let it empty as it is ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you actually trying to connect to a server through a proxy?  Or just authenticate to a server?

Comment: authenticate, then I hope to call a method from it

Comment: none... what do you recommend me? i am new to C#